How to prove axiom 1 is a tautology in a formal sytem
We have the following code:
Section Formula.
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Context {atom : Set}.
(* Parameter atom : Set. *)
(* Generalizable Variable atom. *)

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Declare Scope formula_scope.
Open Scope formula_scope.
Declare Custom Entry formula_view.

Notation "x" := x (x ident, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "~ p" := (f_not p) (p custom formula_view at level 1, in custom formula_view at level 1).

Notation "p -> q" := (f_imp p q) (q custom formula_view at level 4, in custom formula_view at level 4).

Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom formula_view at level 5, at level 0).

Definition conjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~(A -> ~B)$.
Notation "A /\ B" := (conjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 2, in custom formula_view at level 2, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition disjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~A -> B$.
Notation "A \/ B" := (disjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 3, in custom formula_view at level 3, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition equivalence (A B: formula) : formula := $(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)$.
Notation "A <-> B" := (equivalence A B) (B custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 5, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* Equality of formulas is decidable. *)
Lemma formula_eq (A B : formula) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  now apply atom_eq.
Qed.

(* Instead of working with lists of assumptions we shall work with
   sets of assumptions. A set of formulas can be represented by its
   characteristic map formula -> Prop. *)

(* Element-hood relation between a formula and a set of formulas. *)
Definition elem (A : formula) (Γ : formula -> Prop) := Γ A.
Infix "∈" := elem (at level 77) : formula_scope.

(* The empty context. *)
Definition empty : formula -> Prop := fun _ => False.

(* The union of two sets of formulas. *)
Definition union (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) (A : formula) := A ∈ Γ \/ A ∈ Δ.
Infix "∪" := union (at level 78, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* The subset relation between sets of formulas. *)
Definition subset (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) :=
  forall A, A ∈ Γ -> A ∈ Δ.
Infix "⊆" := subset (at level 79) : formula_scope.

Fixpoint eval (value : atom -> bool) (f : formula) : bool :=
  match f with
  | f_atom a => value a
  | f_not f => negb (eval value f)
  | f_imp f1 f2 => implb (eval value f1) (eval value f2)
end.

Definition logically_implies (A : formula) (B : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v A) -> is_true (eval v A).

Definition tautology (f : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v f).

Theorem axiom1_tautology (A B: formula) : tautology $A -> B -> A$.
Proof.
  unfold tautology.
  intros.
  unfold is_true.
  (* destruct A *)
  (* - false: evaluate formula, get true result *)
  (* - true: destruct B, evaluate formula for every case, get true *)

The proof must be very simple if the atomic elements of formula were booleans, and the informal proof looks like this:
We have a formula: A -> (B -> A)
A can be aither true or false.
If A is false, then we get:
false -> (B -> false)
this implication is always true
If A is true, we get:
true -> (B -> true)
If B is false, we get:
true -> (false -> true) = true -> true = true
If B is true, we get:
true -> (true -> true) = true -> true = true
We studied every get and the formula is equal to true everywhere. That's a proof that the formula is a tautology.
How to formalize it?

Doing destruct A is not the right approach, that means you want to inspect the shape of your formula (i.e. is it an implication, an atom, etc.) This is not what is going on in the on-paper proof.
Instead, the on-paper proof does a case distinction on whether A is true or false. Formally, this is a case distinction on the truth value of A in the current environment. Or more formally, it is whether eval v A is true or false.
The easy way of discovering this is by maximally unfolding the definition of eval here and "computing" the result. The command is simpl or cbn, and running this leads to the following goal:
implb (eval v A) (implb (eval v B) (eval v A)) = true

As you can see, this uses the Coq implb operator on booleans, and the inputs are precisely the results of evaluating A and B under current environment v, that is, eval v A and eval v B.
We can now do the case analysis on eval v A, by running destruct (eval v A).
This yields two goals:
implb true (implb (eval v B) true) = true
-----
implb false (implb (eval v B) false) = true

It turns out that for technical reasons, we also need to destruct eval v B, because implb is defined by case distinction on the first argument. So we can instead do destruct (eval v A), (eval v B).
This creates four new goals, but all of these are trivial, since they hold by computation. As you can see by running simpl or cbn in either, they all unfold to true = true. So we can now run reflexivity in each to close the goal and finish our proof.
Thus, in short, your proof is solved as follows:
Theorem axiom1_tautology (A B: formula) : tautology $A -> B -> A$.
Proof.
  unfold tautology.
  intros.
  unfold is_true.
  simpl.
  destruct (eval v A), (eval v B); reflexivity.
Qed.

